# Why are dictionaries faster than lists in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
>>> timeit.timeit('test.append("test")', setup='test = []')
0.09363977164165221
>>> timeit.timeit('test[0] = ("test")', setup='test = {}')
0.04957961010914147
```

I even tried again with a loop, and same thing:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(10): test.append(i)', setup='test = []')
1.3737744340367612
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(10): test[i] = i', setup='test = {}')
0.8633718070233272
```

Why is the list slower?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask yourself: Why are you expecting lists to be faster?

Comment: @Wboy Why would I ask myself that?

Comment: @DavidTan Because you wrote "I expected lists to be faster". It could be easier to refute that specific expectation than answer something specific to the general python implementation here.

Comment: Perhaps that was a mistake to type; it's completely unnecessary and irrelevant to my question. I take it back. My sincere apologies sir.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `list.append` and `dict.__setitem__` are both O(1) average case.  Of course they will have different coefficients, but there is not really any blanket reason to say that one or the other will be the faster.  The coefficients may change depending on implementation detail, too.

Secondly, a more fair comparison would be to remove the attribute resolution overhead:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('test[0] = ("test")', setup='test = {}')
0.0813908576965332
>>> timeit.timeit('test_append("test")', setup='test = []; test_append = test.append')
0.06907820701599121
```

The lookup of the method name on the instance is relatively expensive, when you are looking at an extremely cheap operation such as `append`.

I also see lists being consistently a little faster, once there is some data inside.  This example is python 3.5.2:

```
>>> dict_setup = 'import random; test = {random.random(): None for _ in range(1000)}'
>>> list_setup = 'import random; test = [random.random() for _ in range(1000)]; test_append=test.append'
>>> timeit.timeit('test[0] = "test"', setup=dict_setup)
0.06155529400166415
>>> timeit.timeit('test_append("test")', setup=list_setup)
0.057089386998995906
```

Comment: I tried running that, I'm getting 0.063 for [] and 0.047 for {}. But you're right, it did make an improvement from .append()'s 0.094. Though the question still remains, because lists are still slower (at least for me)

Comment: In response to the most recent edit, I'm still getting faster times from the dict_setup (0.056) than list_setup (0.061). Running Python 3.5.1, Intel Lynnfield, Windows x64

Comment: Well, what can I say? You should explain your reason for expecting the `list.append` to be faster.  I don't think it's a reasonable expectation.